# Get properties from another class (matlab)

Tags: matlab

Is it possbile to get properties from another class in MatLab?

I have two classes: `ProjectTable`and `AllProjectTables`.
In `ProjectTable` I have tried with the following:

```
properties (GetAccess = ?AllProjectTables)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you give more detail about what doesn't work? See answer below for working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
classdef ProjectTable
    properties (GetAccess = ?AllProjectTables)
        Value
    end
    methods
        function obj = ProjectTable(val)
            obj.Value = val;
        end
        function r = addTwo(obj)
            r = obj.Value + 2;
        end
    end
end

classdef AllProjectTables
    properties
        Project_Table
    end
    methods
        function obj = AllProjectTables(project_table)
            obj.Project_Table = project_table;
        end
        function r = test(obj)
            r = obj.Project_Table.Value;
        end
    end
end
```

And test:

```
  >> a=ProjectTable(45)

  a = 

    ProjectTable with no properties.

  >> a.Value
  You cannot get the 'Value' property of ProjectTable.

  >> b=AllProjectTables(a)

  b = 

    AllProjectTables with properties:

      Project_Table: [1x1 ProjectTable]

  >> b.test

  ans =

      45

  >> b.Project_Table.Value
  You cannot get the 'Value' property of ProjectTable.

  >>
```